# Is there a adjective for someone with high pain tolerance?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm trying to describe a character in a story, but all I can think of is high pain tolerance. I think it's a bit weird in the scenario though.

Comment: Are you talking about someone that can withstand torture, or someone that does not feel pain? Stieg Larsson wrote about such a person in his 2nd book. i.e. "...the huge blond guy". It is a congenital infirmity called CIPA.

Comment: I like this question, but you need to provide some more context, as well as a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your character is **stoic**:

> not affected by or showing passion or feeling.
>   *especially* : firmly restraining response to pain or distress —[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic)

For example:

> #### Study could explain why some people are more **stoic** than others, researchers say
>
> It's been a mystery why some people can withstand pain better than others. —[Genes May Help Determine Your Pain Threshold](https://consumer.healthday.com/health-technology-information-18/genetics-news-334/genes-may-help-determine-your-pain-threshold-686866.html)

Comment: "stoic" is not the word for this question.  As your definition says, "firmly restraining response", which is not the same as not experiencing.  My own family is very pain tolerant.  My wife didn't refuse an epidural because she wanted to feel pain, it was because she could put up with it.  My children were prescribed opioids when they had their wisdom teeth extracted, but they didn't bother taking them, not even Asprin®.  I myself haven't taken a "pain reliever" for decades.  If I feel pain, and I know what is causing it, I can simply ignore it.  That isn't stoicism.

Comment: @RayButterworth It seems like we disagree on what "pain tolerance" means. I interpreted it the same as [this article](https://www.healthline.com/health/high-pain-tolerance): "Your pain tolerance refers to the maximum amount of pain you can handle. This is different from your pain threshold. Your pain threshold is the minimum point at which something, such as pressure or heat, causes you pain."

Comment: But I *am* talking about pain tolerance, not threshold.  I'm not insensitive to pain. But I've never felt pain so intense that I couldn't simply ignore it and live with it.  It's only if I don't know the cause of the pain that I have any problem, and then the problem is with determining the cause, not with allieviating the pain.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm an anesthesiologist, so expert opinion here.  Stoic is actually the word used in our literature to describe this.  You have a higher pain threshold which is what makes you have a higher pain tolerance.  You still feel the painful stimulus, but it does not trigger as vigorous a pain response in your brain.  The threshold required to trigger that same response in your thalamus is higher than average.

Comment: @Laurel +1, see my other comment.  This is the term frequently used in anesthesia literature to describe people with high tolerance for pain.

Comment: @DavidM, I'm more used to the classical definition of stoic.  But I *do* feel pain.  I feel and react quite normally to acute pain.  But for any chronic pain I am simply able to deliberately decide to ignore it.  A classical stoic would feel the pain and embrace it, believing that physical suffering improves one's spiritual side.  I prefer to avoid pain, but when it does happen, I simply accept its message and don't allow it to control me.

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm exactly the same way.  It's a fascinating field of study.  There are tribes that don't react to pain at all.  People used to think they didn't feel it.  But, with further study, their threshold levels are the same but they're culturally not prone to reaction.  They feel pain but don't make any outward sign. -- These people are stoics.  Different from you and me.  We feel pain but it affects us less than average.  i.e. It doesn't trigger the same degree of painful stimulus in the brain.

Comment: @DavidM, but I *do* feel pain.  I remember once dropping a rock on my foot, and I definitely felt pain.  So much so that everything turned white and I almost fainted.  But once I understood the source of the pain, and that I was no longer in danger, I was able to suppress the feeling and for the most part ignore it.  So my threshold for pain might be quite low, while my tolerance for pain is quite high.  I really don't want to experience pain, whereas a classic stoic is *indifferent* to pain and an ascetic actually *wants* to feel pain, believing the experience helps purify their "soul".

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple word, but [**tough**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tough): capable of tolerating extreme strain, hardship, or severe labor.

Tough is especially applicable in a character description.

> After years of military service, bar room brawls, and countless injuries without a word of complaint, no one doubted that Joe was tough.

Answer (score 0):

Resilient. A resilient person does not let external influences affect him in an uncontrolled manner.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Consider adding a dictionary definition (See [*How to reference material written by others*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)).